# Kubuntu 20.04 / KDE: How to disable Ctrl+D (delete desktop icon) hotkey?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, icons

I use my desktop primarily for working in terminal windows and I'm used to close them by typing Ctrl+D (=EOF in terminal), it sometime happens that I erroneously type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> outside of my terminal windows, especially if I have a dozen of such terminal windows and I want to closed them quickly.

What then happens is that one of my icons on desktop is removed.

I already searched in System settings -> shortcuts but I could not find the Ctrl+D definition anywhere.
Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu do you use? I'm using 21.10 and cannot reproduce this behaviour on my desktop, Ctrl+D closes the terminal, but outside the terminal it does nothing.

Comment: I'm using version 20.04.3.
Maybe I wasn't able to describe my problem correctly. I'm not talking about an issue of KDE. I consider it a feature being able to delete an icon from desktop with a hotkey. In my specific case though, it's a bit different. I have "focus follows mouse" active, because I very frequently switch between (terminal) windows and just start typing w/o need to click. As such, when the last terminal window is closed with CTRL+D and I by mistake type an additional CTRL+D, the focus sometime happens to be on a desktop icon, which then gets removed.
Thank you!

Comment: An addition: I now tried explicitely to delete an icon with CTRL+D and it didn't work either, so maybe I'm completely on the wrong way. I can only say that sometimes after colsing all my xterm windows an icon is missing, and in most cases (or always?) it's the icon of one of the firefox profiles. I suppose it's because those icons are the ones that I most frequently use so the chance is high that behind the xterms one of them had the last focus (?). Again: maybe I'm completely wrong with my suspect, especially after my test with CTRL+D right now ...

Comment: You should test again. I have tried Ctrl-D to delete a file on the desktop, and can confirm it. File has to be selected and the desktop (not any window) have the focus. (So that happens only if your terminal is not maximized nor full screen and you click the desktop area.) I couldn't find the shortcut settings for Ctrl-D to delete selected desktop file, but it certainly works. You should ask on https://forum.kde.org/ too. This seem like a bug to me. That shortcut is not documented, absent in settings and does the same as Delete key, so it's useless, beside its confusion with the terminal key.

Comment: I have never heard of that Ctrl-D to delete until now, but nor have I heard of Ctrl-D to quit terminal. (Couldn't Alt-F4 be used instead?) Ctrl-D to delete desktop items is a bug or forgotten useless option: Delete key does the same but —unlike Delete— Ctrl-D only works on the desktop, which makes no sense. In Neon with Plasma 5.23.80 (a sort of 5.24 preview) this bug is absent.

Comment: Ctrl+d is a very common shortcut for closing terminals/connections @cipricus. In any case I tested this with Kubuntu 21.04 and couldn't replicate. Albert Cester, are you using any different keyboard layouts?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that in Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, Plasma 5.18.5 Ctrl-D will delete a file on the desktop (accessed in the desktop view, **not** in the file manager). The file has to be selected and the desktop view (not any window) have the focus. (Considering the interaction with the terminal as described in question, that happens only if the terminal is not maximized nor full-screen and it loses focus in favor of the desktop by clicking a file there.)

I don't have an answer on how to remove it, and I think ***this must be a bug***, although non-reported and completely unnoticed until here. I have initially thought of it as a remnant of an old feature that was forgotten about by the KDE people, but in the end I think it's simply a sudden bug around version 5.18 of Plasma - for the following reasons:

- Absent in Kubuntu 20.04/Plasma 5.18 settings, that shortcut is [***not documented***](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html). It doesn't appear in the context menu when selecting the file either.
- I couldn't find ***anything*** about it [on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=kde+ctrl%2BD&oq=kde+ctrl%2BD&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2.3428j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ***at all***. (It might have been absent before Plasma 5.18, although  it's hard to test now).
- It was ***removed in more recent versions of Plasma***. (Tested with Plasma 5.23 in Kubuntu 22.04 daily, Fedora and Neon. Cannot be sure about Plasma above 5.18 and before 5.23).

It is also clear it never made much sense. Beside its confusion with the terminal key, it provides nothing more than the Delete key, which (more economically) does the same, and more: unlike Delete, Ctrl-D only works on the desktop, and not in the file manager, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much cipricus for the explanation. I'm curious to see whether this bug is really fixed with one of the the next plasma versions, because as I said, it's for years I run into that issue every once in a while. We'll see.
I think at that point my question can be closed.
Thank you again!

Comment: So this is an older bug, before Plasma 5.18? Most certainly it was fixed in later versions. Your question is not closed. - Here questions are "closed" if they are wrong. Yours is excellent. If questions are answered it's you (the original poster of the Q) who is expected to mark the answer as definitive (also up-vote them). But others can post new answers and you can change your mind and mark a new one as definitive.